# Paypal rest api multiple billing agreement

Tags: php, rest, api, paypal

Good day,

Is it possible to create multiple billing agreement on one transaction process, using paypal rest api?

If somebody have a solution, please comment on my post.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, it unfortunately isn't possible using the current SDK. It used to be possible on the old SOAP endpoints where you could create 10 together, but that is now deprecated.

Hope you find a workaround!